# identify the number of decimal places based on the format string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to identify the number of decimal places based on the format string like `#.00` should return `2`.

```
###,#.  === > 0 
###,#.00000 ===> 4
```

Is there a better way than just looping through the characters and checking if their index greater than dot and incrementing a count...

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that the input will only have zeros after the decimal, you could subtract the string's Length from the IndexOf(".").

```
(str.Length - str.IndexOf('.') - 1)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to count zeros after the decimal. I'd personally use a LINQ statement. It won't be any more performant, but it'll look nicer.

```
str.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Count(c => c == '0')
```

Of course, there are other caveats. To come up with a "correct" answer, you'll have to provide more information about how you want to handle cases like this:

```
(12345.4321).ToString("#.##") // 12345.43
(12345.4321).ToString("#.#####") // 12345.4321
(12345.4321).ToString("#.#####-0") // 12345.43210-0
```

So do you need to count hashes because they *could* cause an extra decimal place to appear, or not count them because they might not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the format to format the number 0, count the number of characters and subtract 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LastIndexOf`, passing in `.` and use the result with the length of the string.

```
return fmtString.Length - fmtString.LastIndexOf('.') - 1;
```

You should make sure that the string does contain a `.`, as otherwise `LastIndexOf` will return -1.